# What can we use instead of nstimer?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gps, cllocationmanager

I can get the GPS location in the background using `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]`, but I don't know how to schedule it. I have used NSTimer for scheduling but many of them are saying that NSTimer will get expire if the application enters background.

I want to know how to schedule calling the method , if we are not using NSTimers.

Comment: Check this out -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388781/scheduling-task-in-iphone

Comment: I don't want to go for Local/Remote Push Notifications, I want to Schedule it. In that one of the user mentioned to use scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval , I am using the same in my app which are 
theTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(Location) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] . The Timer will won't expire ??

Comment: @user562100- if you don't want to use all these, then u have to go for threads.

Comment: @RIP - I wish i will go either for Push Notifications or Timers. I have used scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval (20 min),its working FINE. But many of them say that it will expire, is that true? If not, I was wondering why it is working for me. Can i use that scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval ?

Comment: i have  used it several times, but i won't face any issue with it. It always works fine for me...i think you can go ahead with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides 5 kinds of app task to run in background:

> - Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
> - Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as    a navigation app
> - Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
> - Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content
> - Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

[Refer this link for location updates while app is in background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Also refer this tutorial for further help](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/)

Answer (score 1):

We can use Push Notification instead of NSTimer for scheduling as shown:-

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Hope it helps.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(_yourMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay_in_milliseconds];
```