# Displaying NSString in a label every n minutes

Tags: iphone, ios, sleep

I am having a label and an array which consists of 10 string values.I know how to display the text in that label.But now,For every 1 minutes I want to display each and every string from that array to the label .Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: use NSTimer with 1 minute interval

Comment: I can use the timers but i have went through some documents that they will get expire when the device is locked or some exceptional cases. NOTE : I have added the location services for my application now.

Comment: Not an Xcode question. Retagged. I need to put this comment on a function key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a variable in your class to save the index of current string
2. Write a method which increase the index and update the label with the next string
3. Create a [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) with interval = 60 seconds to call this method repeatly

**Update**

Per your comments I guess what you want to update is the location info? Some references:

- [iOS Multitasking: Background Location](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/)
- [What can we use instead of nstimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169241/what-can-we-use-instead-of-nstimer)
- [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10)
- [iOS App Programming Guide - Tracking the User’s Location](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW25)

Comment: I can use the timers but i have went through some documents that they will get expire when the device is locked or some exceptional cases. NOTE : I have added the location services for my application now.

Comment: So, are you trying to refresh location information on your label? Added some references in my answer.

Comment: Not exactly. I am going to the location service in different area.I have added the location services in my app so that it will support foreground and background execution.

Comment: Why do you want to update the label even when the app is in background? The user is unable to see the change until the app goes foreground again - I think you can update the label at this moment.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeText:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Remember to use `[timer invalidate]` if you want to stop the timer, or you'll have a crash if the target has been released.

Comment: I can use the timers but i have went through some documents that they will get expire when the device is locked or some exceptional cases. NOTE : I have added the location services for my application now.

Comment: while in background, you should not do UI related actions. The HIG is pretty clear about it. Can you explain in more details why you need a background service?

Answer (score 1):

use NSTimer with 60 sec interval, write a method to get the text from the array and display it in the label.

Comment: I can use the timers but i have went through some documents that they will get expire when the device is locked or some exceptional cases. NOTE : I have added the location services for my application now.